# pdf generation using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, prawn

I using prawn to generate a pdf in my project.

I have the below code to generate the table

```
class PdfGenerator < Prawn::Document
  def initialize
    super
    create_table
  end

  def create_table
     table create_array do
       row(0).font_style = :bold
       row(0).align = :center
      columns(0..2).width = 175
      self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD", "FFFFFF"]
      self.header = true
     end
     nil
  end

  def create_array
     table_array = []
     5000.times do
        table_array << ["first_name", "last_name", "state"]
     end
     table_array
  end
end
```

Benchmark Results

```
1.9.3-p194 :027 > Benchmark.bm do |x|
1.9.3-p194 :028 >     x.report {PdfGenerator.new}
1.9.3-p194 :029?>   end
       user     system      total        real
  33.410000   0.000000  33.410000 ( 33.442593)
 => [ 33.410000   0.000000  33.410000 ( 33.442593)
```

array has around 5000 elements in it and while it executes the above code, CPU utilization reaches 100% and it takes more than 30 seconds to generate the table.

Is this common while using prawn? Can i do anything to improve the performance?

Comment: Could you show the array's structure?

Comment: Two dimentional array of 5000 elements with each element looking like `[first_name, last_name, state]`

Comment: Modified the question to have the full class

Comment: Prawn runs on 1 CPU and creating 100+ pages seems to take a while.

Comment: BTW: `Array.new(5000) { ["first_name", "last_name", "state"] }` is a shortcut for creating such arrays.

Comment: @Stefan, Is it a problem with prawn? Would there be any improvement if i go with a different pdf generator?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31427/discussion-between-vimsha-and-stefan)

Comment: What was the result of that chat?

Comment: so have you found any solutions?